# Creating std::vector of nonmovable type

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++17

I have a `std::vector` named `args` (I don’t know the size of the vector at compile time) and a non movable type `NonMoveable`.

I want to create a vector of the same size as args, so that it equals to
`{NonMovable(args[0], additional_arg), NonMovable(args[1], additional_arg), …, NonMovable(args.back(), additional_arg)}`

I don’t need to change the size of the vector later. How do I do that?

I can’t `reserve()` then `emplace_back()` because `emplace_back()` requires moving (to allow reallocation which is not possible in my case)

I do not want to use `std::list` because it is not contiguous.

Comment: @BaummitAugen `emplace_back()` requires MoveInsertable (`reserve` doesn't)

Comment: you don't want to use unique_ptr?

Comment: @andreaplanet, I know about this option, but I'd rather not

Comment: Why not use `std::deque`, which doesn't require movable?

Comment: and what about std::deque::emplace_back ?

Comment: If the object is default constructible, "good" old raw arrays might help you out. If not, possibly a char array of appropriate size and alignment(!) in combination with placement new?

Comment: Is there a possibility to make the class movable?  Normally you don't need to make an object not movable.

Comment: @RiaD: When you say "non-moveable", you mean completely immobile, right? Neither a copy nor move constructor, yes?

Comment: @NicolBolas yes

Comment: You can actually do this (though really not recommended) if `args` is a `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 4):

You can:

- Have a `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` or `vector<optional<T>>` or `vector<some_other_defer_storage_mechanism<T>>` instead of just `vector<T>` - these are all wrapper types that adding some functionality `T` without affecting `T` (`unique_ptr<T>` makes it movable, `optional<T>` ensures default construction so you can construct with the right size then `emplace()` within the `optional`, etc.)
- Use `deque<T>` which does not require movability for `emplace_back` (although you lose Contiguity)
- Write your own dynamic array that is roughly equivalent to a `pair<unique_ptr<T[]>, size_t>` that just allocates space for `n` `T`s and then placement-news onto each of them, ensuring that destruction does the right thing. This isn't so bad to implement - since you won't be changing the size, you need to support a very minimal amount of overall operations.

Whichever one of these is the best answer really depends.

Comment: optional looks like a best choice to me.

Comment: `std::optional` will not work in this case. Even though it has a default constructor, if it's non movable/copyable, neither will `std::optional` itself be. And a vector of unique pointers only assures contiguousness of the unique pointers themselves, and not the actual objects.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `std::optional` will work [just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/gsiuMt). But really the point of listing a bunch of options is that I don't know exactly what OP needs.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the elements to be contiguous, you could use the good old 2 times dynamic array construction:

```
// allocate a dynamic array
NonMoveable *mv = std::allocator<NonMoveable>().allocate(args.size());

// use inplace new to construct the NonMoveable elements
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < args.size(); i++) {
    new(mv + i) NonMoveable(args[i], additional_arg);
}

...  // use the dynamic array

// Explicitely delete the elements
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < args.size(); i++) {
    mv[i].~NonMoveable();
}

// and de-allocate
std::allocator<NonMoveable>().deallocate(mv, args.size());
```

It is rather C-ish but meets the contiguous requirement. Of course this should be encapsulated in a custom container to allow automatic destruction and de-allocation at container destruction.