# Why does this code involving boost::transform_iterator with a non-movable type not work?

Tags: c++, iterator, boost-iterators

This code was inspired by another question on Stack Overflow a few days ago. It attempts to use a transform iterator to construct a `std::vector` containing a non-movable type.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

struct NonMovable {
    NonMovable(const NonMovable&) = delete;
    void operator=(const NonMovable&) = delete;
    NonMovable(NonMovable&&) = delete;  // redundant
    void operator=(NonMovable&&) = delete;  // redundant
    NonMovable(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> args = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int additional_arg = 5;
    auto fun = [&additional_arg](auto arg) { return NonMovable(arg, additional_arg); };
    std::vector<NonMovable> v(boost::make_transform_iterator(args.begin(), fun),
                              boost::make_transform_iterator(args.end(), fun));
    for (const auto& item : v) {
        printf("%d %d\n", item.x, item.y);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't compile (https://wandbox.org/permlink/20xMUsCBUg44YmXC). The error message from Clang mentions that the `std::vector` range constructor is disabled because:

> `no type named 'reference' in 'std::__1::iterator_traits<boost::iterators::transform_iterator<(lambda at prog.cc:22:16), std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>, boost::iterators::use_default, boost::iterators::use_default> >'`

But I can't see any reason why this `iterator_traits` specialization should not have a member named `reference`.

Comment: Not movable, not copyable, nor assignable, I wouldn't expect vector to work with it either

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953039/creating-stdvector-of-nonmovable-type/54953118

Comment: Could it be: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/iterator#L491  ?

Comment: It seems `make_transform_iterator` requires `fun` to be [assignable](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html#transform-iterator-requirements). How can that be? A lambda is never assignable right?